# Rules engine for .NET

Tags: c#, rules, drools

We have a business requirement to let power users edit rules for insurance rates and enrollments.   We need a web ui that lets them say "this product is only for people <55 unless they are from Texas and own a poodle" or whatever.  Edit for clarification: Insurance is insane.  The rules differ from product to product, state to state and change constantly.

We looked at a couple of rules engines but the commercial ones are 100K+ and the open source ones don't seem um, finished.  Windows Workflow works if we create the rules ahead of time, but building them at runtime seems to require bypassing code access security.  That's scary.

Are we nuts to reinvent this wheel?  Is there a better alternative for .net?

Comment: Some of the best things are done because of insanity, and if you guys did write your own maybe it could be its own product that you could be making 100K from per sale.

Comment: Wouldn't this be considered business logic that should be baked in?

Comment: You know ... if you were using Java ... :)

Comment: @Perception I would want to know the reason.

Comment: @codesilverback - Haha, doubtful. Seriously, take a look at Drools when you get a chance.

Comment: Have you seen the http://rule.codeeffects.com already? It's exactly what you ask for, I think.

Comment: Have you tried [FlexRule](http://www.flexrule.com)? It is the most affordable commercial rule engine that supports all the complex rules and logic and comes with optimization algorithm. E.g. RETE.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I do not think that the evaluation of the rules will be the challenge. I think that the greater challenge is to *parse* the rules that the user can enter. For parsing the rules you should consider to create some DSL. Martin Fowler has some thoughts about this [here](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/RulesEngine.html). Then maybe [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) then might be worth a look.

For the evaluation part: I work in the finance industry and there are also complicated rules, but I never had to use a rule engine. The means of an imperative programming language (in my case C#) were (until now) sufficient. For some occasions I was considering a rules engine, but the technological risks(*) of a rule engine were always higher than the expected benefits. The rules were (until now) never that complicated, that declarative programming model was needed.

If you are using a object oriented language you can try to apply the [Specification Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern). Eric Evans and Martin Fowler have written a more detailed explanation, which you can find [here](http://www.martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf). Alternatively you can write your own simple rule engine.

(*) Footnote: Somehow you will need to embed the rule engine into your application which is very likely written in some object oriented language. So there are some technological boundaries, which you have to bridge. Every such bridge is a technological risk. I had once witnessed a Java web application using a rule engine written in C. At the beginning the C program sometimes produced core dumps and tore down the whole web application.

Answer (score 10):

I think as with most make vs buy decisions it's always a tradeoff you have to make personally. If you buy an off the shelf solution which costs 100K+ and you're only going to use 1% of it than that is probably some money unwisely spent. However if the product is a perfect fit then you can almost be sure you can never build it for less (assuming they have a lot of experience in that particular field).

So no you're not nuts to reinvent this wheel as long as you're not trying to do everything the  off the shelve product does and just focus on the specific functionality you need and not get yourself tempted by the idea of building a very nice (but expensive) framework for something very simple.

Answer (score 3):

100K isn't chump change, but a decent programmer for a year will almost certainly cost more than that - do you have a cheaper programmer that can do it faster than a year? will it be just as good (for your needs) or better?

Answer (score 2):

This is not quite my field, I came by this question by accident, so I may be off, but I'd take a look at [Wolfram Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/). It is a technical computing environment and multi-paradigm (proprietary) programming language, supporting many programming styles (including rule-based and functional programming). It *has* a very general rule engine at its core. Despite the name and reputation as mathematical software (which it is), it is a general-purpose programming language, very high-level. A subset of it can be compiled to C. It can load external dlls dynamically, and it transparently inter-operates with both Java and .Net platforms. It has a web version - webMathematica (which is based on Java however, jsp+Tomcat, but no one stops you from interfacing it with your .Net - based web layer directly, just some more work). The additional benefit is that, if you ever need any mathematical computations, analysis, plots, statistics, it's all there, and state of the art.

I'd think it should be much faster to develop the functionality you need in Mathematica than in many other languages / solutions (I program professionally in Mathematica, C, Java and Javascript, so can at least compare these languages). The full commercial license should be 2 or 3 K for a single machine (4 cores), I think. It has several parallelization features. The hardest thing in this approach would be to find a competent Mathematica programmer, but someone with a background in functional/rule-based programming (LISP / Prolog, say) should be able to pick up things fairly quickly. Also, it may not be sufficiently fast if you need very high performance - I really don't know how it compares in terms of performance with other rule engines. On occasion, I had a chance to compare in Mathematica a rule-based solution for some problem to the one compiled to C, and I'd say well written rule-based code should be on the level of Python in terms of performance, and on the average perhaps one  order of magnitude or so slower than the one compiled to C. But that was mostly for numerical/computational or data-manipulation-related problems, so I'd think for problems inherently based on rules, the performance gap could be smaller.

One thing I am sure about is that in Mathematica you can create sets of rules of any generality and complexity fairly easily with a small amount of code. It is a best tool for exploratory programming based on rules that I encountered so far, with a very short development cycle. I invite you to visit the [Mathematica tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathematica) here at SO to see what types of problems people are solving with it. For one prominent project written entirely in Mathematica language (15 millions lines of code), check out [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) knowledge engine.

Comment: Of course, with version 8, Mathematica functions can be [compiled](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Compile/tutorial/Overview.html) to native code in the form of a dynamic library that is then linked back in.

Comment: @rcollyer *Some* Mathematica functions, but not those based on rules and patterns.

Answer (score 1):

**Is there a better alternative for .net?**

One option is to use an embedded script engine inside your .net code, like Iron Python.  Give a GUI for your users to make rules, convert "the rule" to Python script, call the Python script engine inside of .Net to execute the script.

**Are we nuts to reinvent this wheel?**

If nothing off the shelf meets your needs then No.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that these things are so intertwined with the how a business uniquely operates it's difficult, if not impossible, to effectively use an off the shelf solution.

I've done something like this two different ways.

The most recent (in VS 2005/Framework 2.0) was to create a base engine that handled the common minimum requirements that would be the case across the board. This would be stuff like name, address, etc. Then I wrote a series of extension DLLs that used common interfaces would be loaded via reflection for specific types/regions, for example, by state or product line. Power users could use a simple app to create an account configuration they needed (configurations were stored in a DB). If things changed, the underlying DLL could be modified or a new one added. I only had to add one new extension DLL during the 4 years I was on this project but there were typically one or two small mods needed a month to the rules.

In a much earlier VB6 project I used a guided VBScript to provide power users with the ability to code certain rules. Although the users knew Excel scripting well and a wizard interface was written to help them do what they needed to do they usually just gave me the job of coding the rules. That plan sort of backfired so that's why I didn't use it again later but instead opted for a more "check this, select that" approach to rule building.

Answer (score 0):

Writing your own engine works if your rules are simple. The more complicated they get, the more time it will take to maintain it.

You can use Drools Server to execute your rules and still do your main application with .NET or whatever language you like. You still need Java for the Drools Server part.